# What does までもが mean in this sentence, and もが in general

Tags: grammar, meaning

I am still reading the 十二国記 novel 月の影 影の海. At the end of the first part, after a rather harrowing day, Yoko is riding a leopard-like magical creature, flying through the night sky, when they are attacked by a multitude of enemy creatures. Eventually trapped, she is thrown off the leopard's back, falling from the sky. She opens her eyes, sees a boar-like creature coming at her, and feels a flesh-tearing impact in her right hand. She hears a creature's scream and her own yell. Then follows this sentence:

それを最後{さいご}に五感{ごかん}までもが闇{やみ}の中【なか】に墜落{ついらく}していった。

I understand the general gist of the sentence - at this point her five senses give in - figuratively joining her body in falling into the darkness.

The trouble I'm having is with the `までもが` there. This is not the first time I run into a `もが` - I've seen `誰もが` already, but it, too, confuses me.

How does が following も work? What is the meaning of this particular case (`までもが`), is there any relation between this construct and `誰もが`, and are there additional examples of such `も＋が` constructs?

Comment: By the way, isn't the book titled 十二国記, instead of 中二国記?

Comment: Yes, fixed the typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a small set of quasi-noun idioms made of question words + `も`, which roughly means "every-X". Since they are nouns, they can theoretically put any kind of postpositions after them. But actually they are only used with `が`, less often `に` or `を`, and sometimes `の` (except for `いつも`, which is a full-fledged noun).

- Who: `誰{だれ}も`, `誰{だれ}もかも`, `誰{だれ}も彼{かれ}も` "everybody"
- What: `何{なに}もかも` "everything"
- When: `いつも` "every time, the usual" (full-fledged noun)
- Which: `どれも`, `いずれも`, `どちらも`, `どの noun も`, `いずれの noun も` "any one, any of ..."

The quasi-nouns may have different accents to ordinary combinations:

> だれも{HLL}が vs. だれも{LHH}いない, どれも{HLL}が vs. どれも{LHH}いらない

The questioned `までも` is considered to be a derivation of them, which could be translated into "everything down to X" or "eventually X (with all other things)". Similar expressions are `さえも` and `すらも`, both with boundary-delimiting particles.

Comment: I wonder how it could be considered a derivation, as no question word is involved. Is there an implied question word that I'm missing?

Comment: My original intention was that, it's contraction of what would be like "までの何もかも", but on second thought, I'm unclear now. The meaning is just what I've given.